# i want to find out who add member to telegram with bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I use python and python-telegram-bot library for handling telegram bot
I can not get any event of member add or member live  from channel
its work perfectly for group but doesn't work for channel
there was many ways but none of them work

I want to get telegram's id of who add member and also get the telegram's id of the member who added

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.